# Link does not work from React Router Dom + hooks + redux + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-apollo, react-hooks

I am doing an app that uses:

- react router
- redux
- typescript
- hooks
- Apollo client

**Problem** 
The component `Link` doesn't work for me. Tried to check many pages for the issue without success. All time I am trying to do a `<Link to='/example>` falls into these errors ( leaving my page in blank)

[image]

Note:  Is a component of mine.

If I am doing a `<Link to='/'>` that doesn't cause any error ( I guess the context is not changing for react router

Here comes the funny fact. With this error, the url changes, and if I refresh, the pages works. So I guess it is a missconfigutarion related with `react-router-dom` more than just the component Link.

Another interesting fact, is that everything works if I add the option `forceRefresh` from the `<BrowseRouter>` component.

**My Configuration**

Here some info about my config

*App.tsx*

```
<Router forceRefresh>
        <Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Route exact path="/" component={IndexIssues} />
          <Route exact path="/show/:id" component={ShowIssues} />
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
```

*IndexIssues.tsx*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { RootState } from '@/reducers'


import * as actions from '@/state/issues/actions'
import { Props, IStateIssues } from './types'
import { setIssues, filterResults } from './IndexIssues.effects'
import { Link, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'

const IndexIssues: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const [filteredIssues, setFilteredIssues] = useState([])
  const [textSearch, setTextSearch] = useState('')
  const [stateIssues, setStateIssues] = useState<IStateIssues>({
    open: true,
    closed: true
  })

  useEffect(() => props.getIssues(), [])
  useEffect(() => setIssues({ props, setFilteredIssues }), [props.issues])

  const handleSearchChange: React.ReactEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    e
  ): void => {
    const newText = e.currentTarget.value
    const { issues } = props
    setTextSearch(newText)
    filterResults({ newText, setFilteredIssues, issues, stateIssues })
  }

  const handleCheckBox: React.ReactEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    e
  ): void => {
    const option: string = e.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase()
    const { issues } = props
    const newState = { ...stateIssues, [option]: !stateIssues[option] }
    setStateIssues({ ...stateIssues, [option]: !stateIssues[option] })
    filterResults({
      newText: textSearch,
      setFilteredIssues,
      issues,
      stateIssues: newState
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/show/5">
        click me!
      </Link>
      ....
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(connect(
    (state: RootState) => ({
      issues: state.issues
    }),
    actions
  )(IndexIssues)
)
```

*types.tsx*

```
export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any>{
  one: string
  getIssues(): any
  issues: any
}
```

Any help can be more than welcome. So far I am working with the `forceRefresh` option but ideally would be to solve the issue...

Thanks!

Comment: Try by changing Fragment to Switch

Comment: Could you include your entire `IndexIssues` component? Better yet, could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: Changing to Switch solves my problem but the component is no rendered at all ( tested in the header and seems is working). Any idea why the component is not being rendered in the case of `Switch`?

Comment: I'll try to provide the code @Tholle . Let met try a couple more movements before :)

Comment: @Nisfan didn't work. Tried to remove `Header` since `Switch` only expects `Route`s. Still with the same problem...

Comment: I added almost the entire code here, just missing a couple components that are rendered, but that shouldn't affect